# What JREs are available for end-users after Java SE 8 on Windows?

Tags: windows, java, jre

Historically it's always been possible to obtain the JRE from Sun and then Oracle. But ever since Java SE 9, Oracle has only provided updates for version 8.

When I build a program on a later JDK in Eclipse and attempt to run it on a machine with this version 8 JRE I get an error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/path/SomeClass has been
>   compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file
>   version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class
>   file versions up to 52.0

There are ways to work around this by using the `java` binary provided by the JDK but this is *not* something that would be expected of the user.

So now, after Java SE 8, where do I direct Winodws users of my software to obtain the latest JRE?

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for a software recommendation is generally off-topic here - see [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software). Consider asking on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . And a hint: "RedHat OpenJDK" :-).

Comment: Looks like it has already been asked and answered on softwarerecs: [Java 11 release that I can use for both development and deployment without cost](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/55078/java-11-release-that-i-can-use-for-both-development-and-deployment-without-cost)

Comment: You can configure Eclipse in the preferences to target any version you like.